# Kill a java swing GUI (for real, everything dead)

Tags: java, swing, resources, kill, terminate

I start my swing GUI programaticaly and store the reference.
I want to kill the GUI on user input to optimize performance.

If I do a dispose on the JFrame, timers and threads are still working.

How can I simply achieve a JFrame termination and all its child threads and resources ?

Comment: To be clear, when the GUI is killed by the user, I want the application to carry on.

Comment: What is it that the GUI is doing that requires a lot of CPU?  If whatever the GUI is doing is *not* consuming a lot of CPU, it hardly matters.  And as an aside.  This question wreaks of "can't see the goal for the strategy".  What is the goal, what actual program feature you are trying to offer via. 'killing the GUI' (which reads like nonsense, BTW)?

Comment: I would even dare to say that if you have UI related `Timer`s and `Thread`s which do not clean themself up when the UI is disposed, you have written a memory leak. And there is no magic call to fix those

Comment: you have to use JProfiler before, there you can find out all opened Objects that stays in the JVM memory

Answer (score 2):

Typically, if something is not possible in Java, it is because it is not portable on multiple platforms. The design decision to disallow closing of Java SWING Event Handlers may be because some operating systems disallow starting a GUI process twice.

Then again, why do you think it is important to close these threads? Ask yourself the question: is it because they annoy you when looking at the program in debug mode, or is there a real **measurable** performance impact?

Comment: In my case, my users can kill the GUI and the restart it with a console UI. If done over months, it can be significant.

Comment: @LucasM: Please give us a simple, reproducable example of the significance. `while(true) {JFrame frame = new JFRame(); frame.setVisible(true); frame.dispose();` does not leak any memory or create more than three threads.